# I am having problem with doing diagonal cut for two clickable background in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I am only 3 months in React-Native, and I was going through a lot of styling and shaping, and I encountered a problem with this diagonal cut, every time I try to use dimensions, it always ends up with no image and no text, I think I am missing something obvious, but I gave up on searching and trying it has been almost 2 weeks experimenting with dimensions.my code and what i tired below and the images can be seen if you copy and paste the links generated by stackoverflow.

```
[![Expected results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flJyJ.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flJyJ.jpg)
[![What my current selection screen looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUoyZ.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUoyZ.jpg)
[![when i try and use dimensions and try to cut it diagonal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYprq.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYprq.png)

`import { StyleSheet, Text, View, StatusBar, ImageBackground, TouchableOpacity, Dimensions } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'

const OnBoarding = ({navigation}) => {
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor:"transparent"}}>
      <StatusBar barStyle="light-content" backgroundColor='black' />
      {/* background one image */}
      <TouchableOpacity style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor:'transparent'}} onPress={()=> navigation.navigate("Selection")}>
        <ImageBackground source={require('../assets/images/w20.jpg')} resizeMode='stretch' style={styles.image}>
          <Text style={styles.titleText}>THE WORLD</Text>
          <Text style={styles.surText}>Start playing now!</Text>
        </ImageBackground>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      {/* background two image */}
      <TouchableOpacity style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor:'transparent'}} onPress={()=>navigation.navigate("About")}>
        <ImageBackground source={require('../assets/images/wp21.jpg')} resizeMode='stretch' style={styles.image}>
         <Text style={styles.titleText}>HOW TO LIVE</Text>
         <Text style={styles.surText}>Learn how to play!</Text>
        </ImageBackground>
      </TouchableOpacity>           
    </View>
  )
}

export default OnBoarding

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  image:{
    flex:1,
    width:'100%',
    backgroundColor:'transparent',
    borderRightWidth: Dimensions.get('window').width,
    borderTopWidth:225,
    borderLeftColor: 'transparent',
    borderRightColor: 'transparent',
  },
  titleText:{
    flex: 1,
    fontSize:42,
    fontFamily:"Philosopher-Bold",
    textAlign:'center',
    textAlignVertical:'bottom',
    color: 'white',
    textShadowColor: 'black',
    textShadowOffset: { width: -1, height: 0 },
    textShadowRadius: 30,
  },
  surText:{
    flex: 1,
    fontSize:22.5,
    textAlign:'center',
    fontFamily:"Philosopher-Regular",
    textAlignVertical:'top',
    color: 'white',
    textShadowColor: 'black', 
    textShadowOffset: { width: -1, height: 0 },
    textShadowRadius: 30,
  },
})
```

Comment: Please check this link - https://www.codedaily.io/tutorials/The-Shapes-of-React-Native

Comment: that did not help at all, shaping the image and make it clickable, i am finding it hard, but thanks for your reply, i appreciate it